# Log failed login attempts on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

I'd like to create an script to automatically ban (via .htaccess) any user that makes an incorrect login attempt, but I see Wordpress doesn't write any log including this info.

I have also seen there are some plugins thaat record this info, but they record this log on database, not on a log file.

Does anyone know how I can generate a log file that includes all failed login attempts on my wordpress-based site?

Thanks!

```
     Jorge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a WordPress Plugin that logs failed login attempts to the apache error log:

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed' );
function login_failed( $username ) {
    error_log("user $username: authentication failure for \"".admin_url()."\": Password Mismatch");
}
```

I use this to block multiple login attempts with fail2ban.

Comment: Thanks Gerald!

How should I insert this plugin into my wordpress? Do I have to update any of the Wordpress core files?

Comment: WordPress provides [extensive documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) on how to write a plugin.

Comment: Thanks Gerald! Now I have your plugin up and running!